# PHP code purely in sql

Tags: php, sql, t-sql

I have code in PHP and i want it to make only sql like

table content

```
word   size place
small  10   home
large  18   outside
dog    11   home
cat    6    home
dog    20   outside
small  99   outside
```

The PHP code isnt absolutly correct, but you will see what i need.

```
$input = array("small", "dog");
$place2 = array();
$sql1 = SELECT word,size,place FROM TAB WHERE word = input[0];
$sql2 = SELECT word,size,place FROM TAB WHERE word = input[1];

if ((($sql1['size'] - $sql2['size']) == 1) && ($sql1['place'] == $sql2['place']) ) {
   $place2[] = $sql2['place'].$sql2['word'].$sql1['word'];
}
```

and output $place2[] like a result of query

Is it possible to make this purely in sql without using PHP code? I mean just make some query (Tquery) that will compare values from two different queries and output array of place and word values that will accept that if statement? i need that because db is faster than php and i have a lot of rows

Comment: PHP is going to execute faster than SQL afaik.

Comment: crush is correct. For straight selects mysql will generally be faster, but when you start needing calculated conditions, you'll often find that PHP performs better.

Comment: are you using mysql or sql server or something else? a stored procedure would be a good way to achieve this

Answer (score 2):

PHP would probably be faster/more efficient, but if you really want a query to do it:

```
SELECT CONCAT(`b`.`place`, `b`.`word`, `a`.`word`) AS `output`
FROM `tab` `a`
JOIN `tab` `b` ON `b`.`word`='dog'
WHERE `a`.`word`='small'
   AND `a`.`size`-`b`.`size` = 1
   AND `a`.`place`=`b`.`place`
```

As I said, though, the PHP version is probably far more efficient.